# Script to connect to vpn then open rdp

Tags: vpn, remote-control

I work in the field connecting to my clinic software via Microsoft's RDP over a vpn connection.

So every call I go to, I  start or restart the vpn, then reconnect the RDP.

I'd like to write a script to do it in one click.

It seems like tasker would be an option, but all the articles I have seen have been using Open VPN, not the standard VPN that comes with Android.